When I build a GRPC solution the MSBUILD cannot resolve the appropriate toolchain on Mac OSX
I'm literally going crazy: I can't build any GRPC project any more and I can't find a solution.
When I run the build command (dotnet build) I receive the following error:
mr@bogobox GrpcLab % dotnet build
MSBuild version 17.9.8+b34f75857 for .NET
  Determining projects to restore...
  All projects are up-to-date for restore.
/Users/mr/.nuget/packages/grpc.tools/2.62.0/build/_protobuf/Google.Protobuf.Tools.targets(291,5): error MSB6004: The specified task executable location "/Users/mr/.nuget/packages/grpc.tools/2.62.0/tools/macosx_aarch64/protoc" is invalid. [/Users/mr/temp/dotnetlab/grpclab/GrpcLab/GrpcGreeter/GrpcGreeter.csproj]

Build FAILED.

Analyzing the message I see the reference to the architecture macosx_aarch64 that sounds strange to me.
My laptop is an Apple M1 Pro (arm64). It seems like Msbuild fails to resolve the proper architecture or something related.
I've tried to reinstall the grpc tools but the error persists.
The above error is generated on a fresh new Grpc service created from dotnet template.
Any idea?

When you say "any more" - did it work before with the same build file? What CPU does your machine have?

Yes, it worked for me in the past. My box is an arm64 (Apple M1 Pro)

New day, fresh mindset.
I've examined the msbuild protobuffer target file and found that the path is resolved, after some logic, by concatenating two environment variables PROTOBUF_TOOLS_OS and PROTOBUF_TOOLS_CPU that on my system are:
PROTOBUF_TOOLS_CPU=aarch64
PROTOBUF_TOOLS_OS=macosx

Fixing the former to 'x64' will re-establish the expected behaviour.
The last step is to research the root cause of this, possibly, misconfiguration.
